# SQL Aggregate Functions COUNT

Tags: sql

How would you get multiple values from an aggregate function to display? For example here where Binding is a field and it must count the amount of books per each type of binding in the database. So from the Binding column, it would count the total number of paperbacks, hardcovers, etc. and display them. Books per binding is also not a field in the database so I'm stumped on how to generate that.  I've only managed to be able to display one set at a time but not in a table format.

```
 SELECT
   COUNT(Binding)
 FROM
   Books20m
 WHERE
   Binding = 'Paperback'
```

This image is basically what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for `group by`:

```
SELECT Binding, COUNT(*)
FROM Books20m
GROUP BY Binding
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried group by by I didn't have the order by count.